# Как правильно реализовать фильтрацию выборку постов по странам и городам?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress.
Есть посты, у каждого есть метки (Страна и город).
Нужен такой функционал.
При нажатии на кнопку выводится список стран -> Юзер выбирает страну и в список подгружаются посты с меткой выбранной страны -> Потом появляется кнопка выбора города -> Дальше все по аналогии.

Меня интересует как сгенерировать такие списки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

- Вы должны сделать две таксономии country и city.
- У City должна быть связь с Country например через метаполе.
- Затем в поле страна вы выводите все ваши термины country.
- При выборе country с помощью AJAX вы ищите все термины таксономии City у которых метаполе равно id термина Country.